# why give me back Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null?

Tags: laravel

```
public function importProd(Request $request) {

        $uploadedFile = $request->file('file');
        $filename = var_dump(time().$uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName());

        Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs(
            '/',
            $uploadedFile,
            $filename
        );

        Excel::import(new ProductImport, storage_path('app/'.$filename));

        Storage::delete($filename);

        return back();
    }
```

why give me back Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null ?
is the variable poorly defined?

Comment: You should first validate if `$request->file('file')` actually exists

Comment: Is `$request->file('file')` set? I would also remove the `var_dump()` from your `$filename`

Comment: provide your blade file

Comment: I removed it, but the final problem already worked was the content of the file

Comment: but now give me this error ErrorException Undefined offset: 20

Comment: You have to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`  form action and check `dd($request->all())`

Comment: dd($request->all()) ? where

Answer (score -1):

You should always put null check, modify your function like this

```
public function importProd(Request $request) {
    if($request->hasFile('file')){
        $uploadedFile = $request->file('file');
        $filename = var_dump(time().$uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName());
        Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs(
            '/',
            $uploadedFile,
            $filename
        );
        Excel::import(new ProductImport, storage_path('app/'.$filename));
        Storage::delete($filename);
        return back();
    }
}
```